# Is there any way ( for example window function) to select rows with different number and partition by a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, there are two tables 'authors' and 'books', author has many books

authors:

```
id | name
```

books:

```
id | name | author_id
```

How can i use a single sql statement to query and get this result:

```
book_id    author_id     row_number
3          3          1
4          3          2
10         4          1
11         4          2
12         4          3
17         5          1
18         5          2
19         5          3
20         5          4
21         5          5
```

It is to say that let the books group by author_id and be selected with different counts. We can do this with UNION ALL, just like:

```
(SELECT id AS book_id, author_id, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY author_id) FROM books  
 WHERE author_id = 3 LIMIT 2) UNION ALL (SELECT id AS book_id, author_id, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY author_id) FROM books WHERE author_id = 4 LIMIT 3) UNION ALL (SELECT id AS book_id, author_id, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY author_id) FROM books WHERE author_id = 5 LIMIT 5)
```

, but is there a better way (can window function do this)? Especially with postgresql.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please describe where the row number limits come from

Comment: I wonder what happens when you have joint authors.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select id as book_id, author_id,
       row_number() over (partition by author_id order by id) 
from books 
order by author_id, id;
```

I don't understand what the `limit`s are for.

If you want separate counts, you would need a subquery:

```
select b.*
from (select id as book_id, author_id,
           row_number() over (partition by author_id order by id) as seqnum
      from books 
     ) b join
     (values (2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 5)) v(book_id, lim)
     on b.book_id = v.book_id and b.seqnum <= lim 
order by author_id, id;
```

Comment: thank you go much! The second one is what I want. this is because I think there might be some situation that with different author id, some one want different pagination.